# disk full won't boot even after freeing space

Tags: boot, 20.04, disk-usage

I accidentally ran a task that overfilled my hard drive (120g ssd). I noticed that i was no longer able to save anything. I realized the issue and freed up more than 4GB of space but it still wasnt letting me write to filesystem. I tried to reboot the system and it now gets stuck in a blank screen which lets me type but isn't a shell.

I tried 'Clean' from the Grub recovery and the result is strange.
size   used   avail   use%
118G   114G   0       100

fsck from grub errored out with "/dev/sda1 is mounted e2Sc:cannot continue aborted"

Comment: To do the fsck you need to get into a live system

Comment: @HengYe whats the purpose of the grub option then

Comment: For fixing graphics drivers etc. not for fsck or filesystem repairs, if you're talking about the Ubuntu system recovery